# How to search through and list files that do not contain specific phrase

Tags: grep, search

I am running the same job on around 1000 input files. Around 10% of these will fail, but the only way of checking this is to scroll through the output files and check if it states `completed without error`. To save time is there a way of using the `grep` command to

- Search in a directory specifically through output files only (named `oxxxxx`),
- for those that do not contain the phrase `completed without error`,
- listing these `oxxxx` files in the terminal window.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using [GNU grep's `-L`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) extension:

```
grep -L 'completed without error' o*
```

> -L, --files-without-match
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match.

Without GNU grep:

```
for f in o*; do grep -q "completed without error" "$f" || printf "%s\n" "$f"; done
```

Comment: The "without GNU" example should also include `o*` as the target files for OP's case

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -R <pattern> -L *

-R      recursively search
-L      files without match
```

Example:

```
 touch $(seq 1 100)  # create 100 files
 echo "testing" > 28
 echo "testing" > 32
 echo "testing" > 10
 echo "testing" > 15
 echo "testing" > 95
 echo "testing" > 72
 echo "testing" > 34
 echo "testing" > 25 # eight files with pattern
 $ grep -l test *|wc -l  # files that contains pattern
   8
 $ grep -L test *|wc -l  # files that doesn't contain pattern
  92
```